# How to migrate without downtime from a generic reseller account to Linode?

Tags: migration

I've an account in a shared hosting that have multiple webapps, app1.myserver.com, app2.myserver.com, app3.myserver.com. I need to migrate to another server(VPS) but I need low to no downtime. Email downtime is very critical, so I'm thinking to migrate the webapps first and later the e-mail server.

To achieve this I'm thinking to use the following approach:

1 - Use the "Advanced DNS Zone Editor" in Cpanel of my current webhost to modify the zone file records of my webapps to point to the new server.

For example:

app1.myserver.com.  14400   IN  A   75.98.175.45

to

app1.myserver.com.  14400   IN  A   xx.xx.xx.xx (IP of my new Linode server)

What do you think of this approach? What difficulties can I have following this kind of approach?

Give me some clues

Comment: It may be a good moment to consider moving email away form your apps. I've always found email servers a performance a security risk so I always host mail externally, eg. Google etc. Changing MX records should make that an easy enough migration process. As far as the apps go, you don't mention what they do. Are they writing to a DB you need to keep in sync? If static, then your approach will work fine. If dynamic, you will get two version of the database.

Comment: Hi JayMcTee. I agree with your email perspective. The problem is that I will have more than 100 e-mail accounts. It is very expensive to host email externally with Google. You have any sugestions to host more than 100 e-mail accounts for a resonable price?

Comment: ZoHo offers free email accounts, but that's still a lot to do and likely has limitations. Another approach is to at least virtualize your MTA (I did this with Kerio Connect) so it's somewhat segregated from your apps.